# Haml drop-down menu issue with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
 form_for :radio, url(:radio, :add), :method => :put do |f|
    = f.error_messages
    %p
      = f.label :title, :caption => "Radio Name:"
      = f.text_field :title
    %p
      = f.select :city_name, XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    %p
      = f.label :frequency
      = f.text_field :frequency
    %p
      = f.label :url
      = f.text_field :url
    %p
      = f.submit "Add", :class => 'button'
```

When I put XXXXXXXX as

```
[['Hot','hot'],['Medium','medium'],['Cold','cold']]
```

or even

```
City.all.map {|c| [c.city]}
```

I get:

```
can't convert Array into Hash
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below what solved for me

```
= f.select :city_name, :options => [["Delhi", "Delhi"], ["Mumbai", "Mumbai"], ["New York", "New York"], ["Punjab", "Punjab"]]
```

**:options =>**   was the key... But how come docs does not mention this. May be this is because of gem version difference.

Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

`= f.select :city_name, City.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }` try this

Comment: Don't just toss out code, explain why it should be used. It's the difference between handing out fish, and explaining how to fish.

Comment: Some how update in Hash.rb is giving some issue : - ["<option value=\"Delhi\">Delhi</option>", "<option value=\"Mumbai\">Mumbai</option>", "<option value=\"New York\">New York</option>", "<option value=\"Punjab\">Punjab</option>"]
TypeError - can't convert Array into Hash:
 /Users/himanshu.virmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/padrino-helpers-0.12.2/lib/padrino-helpers/form_builder/abstract_form_builder.rb:279:in `update'

Comment: { :value => field_value(field),
            :id => field_id(field)
          }.update(defaults).update(options).update(error_class(field)){ |_,*values| values.compact.join(' ') }

Comment: `= f.select :city_name, ['pune', 'mumbai','chennai']` try passing an array to it..it shud work..

Comment: Select can accept an array or hash, just see the docs to see the syntax. How it should be passed 
`f.select(:city_name, @cities.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Please select a city'})`
@cities should come from controller

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the options in `options_for_select`. For example:

```
= f.select :city_name, options_for_select([['Hot','hot'],['Medium','medium'],['Cold','cold']])
```

Comment: No difference..Still same result.. :(   can't convert Array into Hash
file: abstract_form_builder.rb location: update line: 278

Answer (score 0):

```
data = %w/hot medium cold/.map { |s| [s.capitalize, s] }
= f.select :city_name, Hash[data]
```

**Hash[data]**